# How to measure the memory usage per active Apache Connection?

Tags: apache, memory-management

I would like to measure the memory consumption for one active Apache connection(=Thread) under Ubuntu.

Is there a monitoring tool which is capable of doing this? 
If not, does anyone knows how much memory an Apache connection roughly needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activate the [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html) module, you'll get a report on /server-status page, there is a more parseable version on `/server-status?q=auto`. If you enable **ExtendedStatus On** you will have a lot of information on processes and threads.

This is the page used by monitoring tools to track a lot of stats parameters, so you will certainly find the one you need (**edit:** if it is not *memory*...) . Be careful with security/access settings of this file, it's a nice tool to check how your server respond to DOS :-)

About memory you must note that Apache loves memory, how much memory per process depends on a lot of things (number of modules loaded - check that you need all the ones you have, number of virtualHosts, etc). But on a stable configuration it does not move a lot (except if you use PHP scripts with high memory limit usage...). If you find memory leaks try to limit the number of requests per process **MaxRequests** (apache will kill him and put a new one).

**edit**: in fact not a lot of memory info in the server-status. About monitoring tools, any tool using SNMP MIB-II can track memory usage per process, with average/top/low values for the different childs (Cacti, Nagios, Munin, etc) if you had a snmpd daemon. Check this [excellent Munin example](http://somethingemporium.com/2009/06/monitoring-per-process-memory-usage-with-munin-memory-mod-php). It's not a tracking of each apache child but it will give you an idea of what you can track with these tools. If you do not need a complete monitoring system such as Nagios or Centreon, with alerts, user managmenent, big networks (and if you do not have a lot of days for books reading) Munin is, IMHO, a pretty tool to get monitoring reports quite fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but everything i get is: 
Total Accesses,
Total kBytes,
CPULoad,
Uptime,
ReqPerSec,
BytesPerSec,
BytesPerReq,
BusyWorkers,
IdleWorkers and 
Scoreboard

Where can i read the memory consumption per request? Am i missing something?

Comment: yes, just checked my monitoring tools, and effectively, no memory info, we track it via SNMP. But at least you've got a detailled cpu info :-). Sorry for that. But as I said, when you've got an idea of memory used (via top command for example) it does not moves a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any tools for doing this. But you could estimate it yourself. Start apache and check how much memory it uses without any sessions. Than create a big number of sessions and check again how much memory it uses.

You could use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to create different workloads.